# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisified because authentication failed

Tags: iis-7.5, load-balancing, wcf-authentication

I'm getting this error message on only one of the two nodes in my web farm.  The code is identical between the two nodes and as best I can tell, IIS is set up identically on both nodes.

The WCF service that they're calling is on a different machine and doesn't have permissions locked down to anything crazy.

Both nodes are using anonymous authentication and forms authentication.  Both have the default user for their app pools both have the IUSR account for the anonymous user.  What else can I check to get node 2 in line with node 1?  As I said, the code is identical across both servers and everything I've looked at in IIS is the same too.  I'm sure there is some other setting in IIS on node 2 that I'm not aware of so if you can think of any other places to look, I'd really appreciate it.

Again this is the exception being thrown (on node 2 only)

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token
>   could not be satisified because authentication failed.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the app pool identity and that seems to have fixed it.  No idea why as they were both using the same identity before...